# How to monitor power usage of a machine without unplugging it?

Tags: power

My APC ES 700 UPS keeps beeping but I don't know why. I'm wondering if I'm overloading it and I'm also curious to know how much power my various devices consume. I'm thinking of buying a power monitor, but not sure which one. Has anyone bought one?

I notice a lot of them require the device you are monitoring to plug into the unit itself, like this one http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/13a-plug-in-energy-saving-monitor-n67fu

I would prefer a unit where you can clip onto the cable and monitor so I don't have to power cycle the monitored device. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

You should install the APC monitoring software. This way, you can find out why its beeping and on top of that, you can monitor the power usage from there.

Comment: Yeah I will do that, I lost the cable, so have ordered a new one. I'm still interested in the power monitoring though for other devices.

Comment: I have one of those monitors. You plug in the powercable into the monitor and the monitor goes into the wall outlet. That way it can read the power. There's no way you can actively measure the power without interupting the normal electricity flow. Even if you were to place something on a power, it would be A. very dangarous, and B. given that electricity follows the path of the least resistence, it would be measuring maybe 2% of the entire power consumption. The electricity would simply not pass the montior that way.